# Create x of x Labels

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have created a label in SSRS 2008. It gathers its data from a single record returned from a query. I would like to add the ability to prompt the user for x number of labels to be printed and display that value on at the bottom of the label as x of x labels (just like x of x pages).

I am stuck on how to produce x number of labels.

Comment: Please show code you've tried so far.

Comment: when I run this script, I receive this error ( "SQL command not properly ended")                                                  with sd1 (ID) as (SELECT 1 AS EXPR1 FROM SYS."DUAL" 
  union all select ID + 1 from sd1 where ID < (:p_intcounter))
SELECT distinct orders.status,
  orders.orderkey
from orders 
where orders.orderkey = '0000000289'
cross join
select ID from sd1

Comment: If I put the sd1 query first, then the actual query after the cross join, I receive a "table does not exist" error. But the individual query's run fine when not combined.

Answer (score 0):

If there will be one label per record returned, add a row number to your dataset.  The value of X should be available somehow - either because you're accepting it as a parameter, or by counting the records in a set, etc.  Then:

```
=CStr(Fields!RowNumber.Value) + " of " + CStr(Parameters!X.Value)
```

Or, if you're aiming to print a dynamic (X) number of the same label that's being populated by a dataset that returns 1 row, things get a bit more complicated.  What I'd recommend doing is making your query duplicate the 1 row as many times as you need for your report.  You could do this in a number of ways, here's just one example that creates a recursive Common Table Expression to populate X number of rows, and then performs a CROSS JOIN to your actual dataset, effectively duplicating the rows by whatever value you set X to:

```
DECLARE @x INT
SET @x = 100

;WITH HelperCTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        1 AS 'blah'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        blah+1 
    FROM 
        HelperCTE 
    WHERE 
        blah<@x 
)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    YourTable
CROSS JOIN
    HelperCTE


/*
    Your server is likely configured with a maximum recursion depth that could 
    prevent the CTE from working.
    Uncomment the line below, and set the "1000" to whatever you need
*/
--OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Then you'll have one record per label you need to print, and you'll have a myriad of ways to deal with it - you can use the rownumber suggestion I already made, you can utilize paging in SSRS, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the information. This surely tells me I am a beginner with this software. I hope you don't mind working me through the process of making this work. I am looking at the second option as the solution since the query will always return only one record. I inserted the code provided, but receive the following error when I run the code. Should this be done in a procedure?

Comment: Grab everything I provided in my example, paste it into management studio.  Replace my "blah" aliases with something less silly. Replace "YourTable" with the name of your table, replace the " * " with the names of the fields you want, AND the aliased field from the CTE ("blah" in my example, but you should change that.  Add on a WHERE clause to filter down to what you need.

The tricky part will be the recursion - to begin, ignore my commented out stuff at the bottom, and use the query as-is.  You can change the value of @X (# of records that will be duplicated) to be whatever you want.

Comment: If/When you do get an error about exceeding the maximum recursion depth, uncomment my last line ("OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000), and then change the "1000" to whatever you have @X set to.  Don't get lazy with MAXRECURSION though and set it to some insanely high number; the recursion limit acts as something of a safeguard against users accidentally running highly inefficient, server-crushing code.

Comment: I have found management studio, but there are many choices. Can you provide more detail on this portion of the set up?

Comment: I am unable to run the with statement. I receive an error. This is an Oracle database ldap. the error is (ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected). Any Ideas? WITH HelperCTE AS
  ( SELECT 1 AS 'ID'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID+1 FROM HelperCTE WHERE ID<10
  )